# What is the time complexity of a linear search performed using 2 pointers?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays

For an array, I'm using a left pointer (pointing to 0) and a right pointer (pointing to end).

For every iteration, if my search element is not found, I increment left and decrement right.
This iteration continues until `left <= right`. Find the code snippet below

```
left = 0
right = length - 1

while left <= right:
    // search logic
    left += 1
    right -= 1
```

What will be worst the time complexity of this algorithm?

Also, is this a type of linear search?

Comment: what is the cost of "search logic"?

Comment: This is not a search, there is not even a key.

Answer (score 0):

$O(n)$, since you still will go through the entire array.

And yes, this is a linear search since $O(n)$ is linear.

Comment: The loop will run only n/2 times right? So wondering if this will be O(n) still.

Comment: of course, constants do not make a difference in $O$ notation